# Label not showing up in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, label, cloudkit

So I'm connecting to a CloudKit database to store a bunch of questions that a user can see. Im outputting the question to a label, however its not showing up. Meaning it won't update. The `println(results.description)` does work though. Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var questions: UILabel!

@IBAction func getNewQbutton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase


    let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "QuestionsTable", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))


    publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil){
        results, error in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }

        else
        {
            self.questions.text = results.description //problem here, won't update
            println(results.description)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`publicDB.performQuery` is an **asynchronous function** that executes in the background.
 **UI updates should always be performed in the main thread.** 
 You can use the following code to set the text in the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.questions.text = results.description
})
```